# How to keep running python script 24/7 on Termux?

Tags: php, python, html, termux, site24x7

I have python script that  im running on my android phone
But the issue is whenever my phone's screen get off or i minimize the app the script get errupt and it doesnt process or works and i have to restart / run it again.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the script as a background process.

`nohup python scripname.py &`

should work.

for more details refer to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal)

Comment: I don't think this is a nice answer because it is not specific to Termux! Using nohup won't do much if the "computer" is halted, as happens with termux when screen is turned off. Acquiring wake-lock through GUI or by using the command `termux-wake-lock` is an option, but it won't work for every phone.